# Logit Regression in StatsModels Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, predict

I am attempting to run a logistic regression with one independent variable, fit the model to data and then return a probability output with a random out of sample input.

```
In [153]: df[['Diff1', 'Win']]
Out[153]: 
   Diff1  Win
0    100    1
1    110    1
2     20    0  
3     80    1
4    200    1
5     25    0

In [154]: logit = sm.Logit(df['Win'], df['Diff1'])

In [155]: result=logit.fit()
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.451400
         Iterations 6

                            Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                    Win   No. Observations:                    8
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                        7
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            0
Date:                Fri, 11 Dec 2015   Pseudo R-squ.:                  0.3177
Time:                        13:49:07   Log-Likelihood:                -3.6112
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -5.2925
                                        LLR p-value:                       nan
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Diff1          0.0207      0.014      1.435      0.151        -0.008     0.049
==============================================================================

In [158]: result.predict(0)
Out[158]: array([ 0.5])
```

I am clearly using the predict function incorrectly, because an input of 0 in this situation should not yield a 0.5.  This result is for a non-fitted example of a logistic model.

I would use simple OLS regression, but would like my model to be bounded by (0,1).

Comment: You don't have a constant included in the explanatory variables. If the linear prediction is zero, then logistic function (i.e. predict) maps to 0.5 probability. So this is correct.